# Hashgacha question

Tags: tanach, commentaries, theology, chasidut-hasidism

What is the explanation that in many cases the Tanakh speaks about nations (e.g. Aram) that Hashem sends to chastise the Jewish nation? It implies that Hashem is able to influence pagan nations, but raises the question that why Hashem didn't influence the Jews to repent instead of sending pagan nations? In order to cause an impact on non-Jewish nations as well? In which manner does He influence foreign nations? Can it be considered as a kind of Hashgacha in order to cause a change in that nation's consciousness?

Comment: הכל בידי שמים חוץ מיראת שמים